# How to dispose previous requests and stop observing the previous LiveData

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-livedata

I am trying to implement an app where I have a searchView, when user searches for something then the apps will call a retrofit request which returns an observable data. In myRepository I convert the the observable to flowable and in myViewModel I convert the flowable to LiveData which I am observing back in myActivity.

But the problem is that if user searches more than once and really fast(before getting previous result) then I want to cancel the previous requests and also dont want to observe previous data.

So the code I am using is like below:

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity  : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        observeRepos()
 }

 fun getReposFromServer(filter_search :String )    {
        mainViewModel.getReposFromServer(filter_search)    }

 private fun observeRepos() {
        mainViewModel.observeReposFromServer().observe(this, Observer { repos ->

            txtVwCount.setText("total item count is: "+repos?.total_count.toString())

        })

        mainViewModel.observeItemList().observe(this, Observer {

            if(!it.isNullOrEmpty())
                if(it.size>0) {
                    mAdapter.setReposInAdapter(it)
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                }
        })
    }


override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        .....
        ......
         searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

          override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                query?.let {
                            if(it.trim().length>0) {
                                clearOldCalls()
                                getReposFromServer(it,"","")      }
                            }
                        return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                     return false;          }

        })
        return true
    }


fun clearOldCalls()   {
        mainViewModel.clearRetrofitCall()
        mAdapter.clearListInAdapter() //in my adapter I just make the list empty by assigning a new list to it
    }

}
```

**MainViewModel:**

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    var liveGitResult = MediatorLiveData<GitResult>()
    val liveItemList =  MediatorLiveData<MutableList<ItemList>>()

     @set:Inject
    lateinit var mainRepository: MainRepository

    fun getReposFromServer(filter_search: String)    {
          val resultFromApiCall_flowable : Flowable<GitResult> =  mainRepository.fetchToDosFromServer(filter_search)
         lateinit var source: LiveData<GitResult>

         resultFromApiCall_flowable.let { 
                 source = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(it)

                  liveGitResult.addSource(source) { todos ->
                       liveGitResult.setValue(todos)
                       liveGitResult.removeSource(source)   }

            }

         var itemList_observable = resultFromApiCall_flowable.map {//it = gitResult
                    gitResult ->
                        var lst = mutableListOf<ItemList>()
                        gitResult.items.forEach {
                                                    lst.add(it)   }

                     lst
            }

        itemList_observable?.let{
                        var liveItemList  = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(itemList_observable)

                        this.liveItemList.addSource(liveItemList){ itemList ->
                        this.liveItemList.setValue(itemList)
                        this.liveItemList.removeSource(liveItemList)    }
            }


     fun observeReposFromServer(): LiveData<GitResult> {
        return liveGitResult
    }

    fun observeItemList(): LiveData<MutableList<ItemList>> {

        return liveItemList
    }

    fun clearRetrofitCall()
    {
        liveGitResult.value =null
        liveItemList.value = null
        mainRepository.clearDisposables()
    }

}
```

**MainRepository:**

```
class MainRepository @Inject constructor(mainApi: MainApi) {

    private val mainApi: MainApi
    private val disposables: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()


    init {
        this.mainApi = mainApi
    }

    fun fetchToDosFromServer(filter_search: String) : Observable<GitResult> {
 lateinit var  returnedData : Observable<GitResult>

      //mainApi.getAllRepo(filter_search) is a retrofit call which returns a   Flowable<GitResult>
             returnedData =    mainApi.getAllRepo(filter_search).subscribeOn( Schedulers.io())
                                                             .onErrorReturn(Function {throwable ->
                                                                Log.e( LOG_TAG, "Something went wrong" )
                                                                 null
                                                             })


              returnedData.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                          .observeOn( AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                          .subscribe(object :Observer<GitResult>{
                                                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                                                    disposables.add(d)  }

                                                override fun onComplete() { }

                                                override fun onNext(t: GitResult) { }

                                                override fun onError(e: Throwable) { }

                                            })

            return returnedData.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);

    }


     fun clearDisposables(){
        if(disposables!=null){
            if(!disposables.isDisposed)
                disposables.clear()
                disposables.dispose()
            }
    }

}
```

Now if i run the app and search multiple times really fast before getting previous result - then its acting weird..

- it shows all results in recyclerview one by one. Shouldn't the previous results get disposed and they won't be converted to liveData?
- also not in a sequence they were called
- moreover, not showing recyclerview Data and textView data at the same time, possibly using observers from different Livedata source

So, where am I doing wrong?

Also how to write the code for `returnedData`  in a single statement instead of writing it in 2 statements that I am doing(*one for calling api and another for overriding subscribe method*).

Answer (score 0):

For similar case I keep a stack of disposables and dispose the oldest subscriptions when starting new. I run OkHtttp requests in them, so when disposing, they got interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

For canceling a previous retrofit request when user creates another request while previous request is still in progress, you can use kotlin's coroutine to achieve this.

You can launch a coroutine with the suspend function which calls your api request and keep the reference of the 'Job' Object returned while launching the coroutine and when your user sends another search request while the previous request is in progress, you can simply check by using 'job.isActive' that if the previous retrofit request is in progress or not and if its active then you can call 'job.cancel()' to stop observing previous liveData and start a new Job.

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
// Job instance
private var job = Job()

fun requestApiForResponse(val searchQuery:String){
 if(job?.isActive) // check if any previous job is running , if true then cancel that 
   job?.cancel()
 job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
   //call your retrofit Request here
 }
}

override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

Check this github's repository [search functionality with liveData and coroutines](https://github.com/rafayali/livedata-coroutine-search-example)